# iOS + Autolayout: Adding constraints to text of UILabel/Button, not frame

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`, and in both cases the frame is a lot bigger than the text presented. I'd rather not change this if I can.

Now, I would like to add a spinner (`UIActivityIndicatorView`) right after the text, how do I do it? What I have right now is a constraint from the spinner's trailing edge to the button/label's trailing edge and a constant of `-40`. This constant if ok for english, but might be wrong for other languages.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please share a drawing/screenshot of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Take leading constraint for `UIActivityIndicator`.
2. Calculate width of the text using this (create `extension`) :

   ```
   func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
       let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]
       let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
       return size.width
   }
   ```
3. Set leading constraint of `UIActivityIndicator`

   to **width + 5** (+ 5 for leaving some gap).

Comment: Spinner needs to go right behind the button's text, which is centred. Combining leading constraint and text width don't seem right. Spinner could be placed at horizontal center of button. Then change the constant of this constraint to `width / 2 + margin`.

Comment: Firstly, OP has never mentioned the text is left aligned or centre aligned. And second, even if it is centre aligned, xAxis for indicator can be achieved by subtracting the width of text from button/label's width.

Comment: A button of 200 and title of 40, leaves space of (200 - 40) / 2 = 80 on both sides. Setting the constraint to -40 (you forgot the minus sign) is totally wrong. Other example: button 200 and title 10: space on both sides (200 - 10) / 2 = 95, but you'd put the spinner at 10. Even further away.